# How do I get the file name and values I am getting form a file into a dataframe python

Tags: python

I am looking to read more than one file that starts with access-team then after I read the files I access them and get the information after username = and put it into a dataframe having a username and filename associated to
Here is the code I currently have but doesn't it doesn't dot it all yet. I am not sure how to read the two files and incorporate them into what I have below. my current results for one file are in one column. I need the dataframe to have the username and the file name.
file name: access-team-rev.txt file two is same way to but it is called access-team-support.txt
files look like this:

[image: file example]

```
import re
filename = 'access-team-rev.txt'
pattern = re.compile(r'username\s=\s(\w+)')
l = [] 
with open(filename, "rt") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if pattern.search(line) != None:
            l.append(line.strip('username = ')) 
            l.append(filename.strip('.txt'))
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you need help with - because you have a list of `[[username_1, filename_1], [username_2, filename_]]` which you can put into a dataframe straight away.

Comment: what did you try? You didn't even import `pandas`.

Comment: you should append as list  `l.append( [ line.strip('username = '), filename.strip('.txt')] )` and after `for`-loop you can do `df = pandas.DataFrame(l)`

Comment: @Chinny84 I Am using a notebook I had it in another line the import pandas as pd  . I wasn't sure how to put it together in one line also I am looking to read more than one file too wasn't sure how to add that in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append as list

```
l.append( [ line.strip('username = '), filename.strip('.txt')] )
```

and after `for`-loop  you can do

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(l)
```

and you will have it in `DataFrame`

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd

l = []

l.append( ['user1','file1'] )
l.append( ['user2','file2'] )

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['username', 'filename'])

print(df)
```

Result

```
  username filename
0    user1    file1
1    user2    file2
```

---

**EDIT:**

Read data

```
import re

filename = 'access-team-rev.txt'
pattern = re.compile(r'username\s=\s(\w+)')

l = [] 

with open(filename) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if pattern.search(line):
            l.append( [ line.strip('username = '), filename.strip('.txt')] )
```

Comment: thank you so much seems I was almost there then. I appreciate it . the only part I am missing now is the reading files part.

Comment: you have to use your code from question to read file but with single `l.append( [ line.strip('username = '), filename.strip('.txt')] )` instead of two separated `append()`. See new code at the end of answer.